Runtime error 216 in FreePascal if two‐dimensional array of chars is disposed
I create a Pointer to a two‐dimensional Char Array, fill it with hash signs (#), output it to the console and free up memory of the pointer. If I use Dispose() a runtime error 216 pops up. If I don’t use Dispose() everything works fine. Why is that?
program GridShower;

type
    Grid = array [1..14, 1..28] of char;
    GridPtr = ^Grid;

const
    LinesNum = 14;
    ColumnsNum = 28;

function FillGrid(CurGrid: GridPtr): GridPtr;
var
    i, j: integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to LinesNum - 1 do
    begin
        for j := 0 to ColumnsNum - 1 do
        begin
            CurGrid^[i][j] := '#';
        end;
    end;
    FillGrid := CurGrid;
end;

procedure ShowGrid(CurGrid: GridPtr);
var
    i, j: integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to LinesNum - 1 do
    begin
        for j := 0 to ColumnsNum - 1 do
        begin
            write(CurGrid^[i][j]);
        end;
        write(#10); { newline char in ASCII }
    end;
end;

{ MAIN PROGRAM }

var
    CurGrid: GridPtr;
begin
    new(CurGrid);
    CurGrid := FillGrid(CurGrid);
    ShowGrid(CurGrid);
    dispose(CurGrid);
end.


If you declare an Array data type:

type
  Grid = array [1..14, 1..28] of char;


then you have to iterate through elements 1 through 14 and 1 through 28 respectively, too.
Your loops:

  for i := 0 to LinesNum - 1 do
  begin
      for j := 0 to ColumnsNum - 1 do
      begin
          { … } CurGrid^[i][j] { … }
      end;
  end;


access CurGrid^[0][0], CurGrid^[0][1], … CurGrid^[1][0], etc. which do not exist (because you declared the dimensions to start at 1) and forgot to access the Array elements at the end (14 or 28 depending on which dimension we’re talking about). This is very bad.
By doing this you probably overwrite some vital data that is placed in front of the pointer’s memory, hence Dispose() goes haywire.
Instead do:
const
  LinesNum= 14;
  ColumnsNum= 28;
type
  // That's the very point of constants: using them EVERYwhere.
  Grid= Array [1.. LinesNum, 1.. ColumnsNum] of Char;

...

  // Choose better variable names; loop from 1.. LinesNum.
  for Line:= 1 to LinesNum do begin
    for Column:= 1 to ColumnsNum do begin

